# Copying feature datasets weekly from EGDB to EGDB (geometric networks included)

Tags: arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, fme-form, geometric-network

I've been trying find a way to copy a few select feature datasets from our main production Enterprise geodatabase environment to a second Enterprise geodatabase. These datasets include geometric networks and the process must repeat weekly (unattended) I've tried various models in ArcGIS Pro essentially deleting previous versions of the data, creating new feature datasets and copying everything over but it ultimately ends up with appended _1's after multiple runs. I'm leaning towards using FME as we just purchased FME server but my exposure to it is limited to say the least.

I was originally using the Feature Class to Feature Class tool but it was decided afterwards to include the Geometric Network which really changes things up. I've been at this for a few days now with little to no success and unfortunately no one in my workplace is really GIS savvy. Can anyone provide a nudge in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Not an FME solution, but the reason you're getting the _1 is because the data exists there already. You'll have to delete the destination data first, then try running the [Copy](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/copy.htm) geoprocessing tool.

Having said that, I don't think FME supports copying an entire feature dataset including the geometric network. But if the geometric network exists in the destination, all you'd need to do is truncate the participating tables and write the data into them using FME. You may need to include a python shutdown script to rebuild the network.

Another option would be to look into esri [database replication](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/working-with-geodatabase-replication.htm).

Comment: The model I built in ArcGIS Pro starts off with a full deletion of the destination feature datasets, step 2 rebuilds them importing the coordinate system of the originals then does a full copy which according to ESRI seems to be the only way to bring them from one location to another. As you said I do not believe FME has a feature dataset tool, but I"m too inexperienced to say for certain. Thank you for the reply. I did start looking at the replication option, good to know I'm thinking along the right lines.